# Asp.net c# SQL Server Update query not working for all columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form that should edit the information in the database. First, I query the database using an URL parameter to get the record and display them in textboxes so I could update them. That part of the code works the issue is when I press submit to update the data after changing what's on the textboxes. Only `LastMod` column gets updated. I think the `page_load` fires twice and overwrites what's on the textboxes before the button click event fires.

Here's the code.

```
public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int aID;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@connectionstring);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            conn.Open();
            aID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            string sql = "select * from Contacts where ID = '" + aID + "' ";

            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adap.Fill(ds);

            txtFName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fname"].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Lname"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmailAdd"].ToString();
            lblLastMod.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastMod"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
            sqlComm = conn.CreateCommand();

            sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE Contacts SET Fname=@FName, Lname = @LName, EmailAdd = @Eadd,LastMod = @LMod WHERE ID=@ID";
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NChar);
            sqlComm.Parameters["@FName"].Value = txtFName.Text.Trim();
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.NChar);
            sqlComm.Parameters["@LName"].Value = txtLName.Text.Trim();
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Eadd", SqlDbType.NChar);
            sqlComm.Parameters["@Eadd"].Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@LMod", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlComm.Parameters["@LMod"].Value = date;
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlComm.Parameters["@ID"].Value = aID;

            conn.Open();
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I tried adding `!IsPostback` in my `Page_Load` method but nothing gets updated even the `LastMod` record.

Thanks for any help I get.

Comment: Side note: using `sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue()` will half the number of lines. You don't need to specify the data types that way.

Comment: Noted Sir, I'll take that into account.

Comment: By putting breakpoint check each value in each line

Comment: Tried that, All values is correct while building the SQL Command.

Comment: you need to have `If(!IsPostBack){}else{ }` when the postback happens which will be on the button click, the Page_Load should fire.. either store the values in `ViewState` or `Session` or place the controls inside an update panel if you want to take advantage of the `__DoPostBack` functionality in javascript then you can add an OnClientClick event to call the javascript and inside the javascrip tcall the Button1_Click1 event.. last modified is not tied to the server posting side of code you need to understand postbacks.. also try enabling ViewState in the aspx page ..

Comment: @gunr2171: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Please check your code that you posted. It has errors so I can't tell if it's just copy/paste error or you actually are missing brackets

Comment: Why are you using `SqlDbType.NChar` instead of `SqlDbType.NVarChar`?

Comment: Even though you are converting the datatype to INT you are begging for injection attacks in the future.  You should always use SqlCommand with Parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a variable, aID, at the top of the page, and you set a value in it in the page load. You then also use it in the click, but you never re-set it. Therefore, for postback, it will not have a value. Move this to page load above your "if not ispostback"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       aID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "select * from Contacts where ID = '" + aID + "' ";
```

Comment: `aID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["ID"]);` this will work if it's being set in a different page so what you are saying is not 100% correct without seeing where the OP initially sets the value of the querystring.. also I am wondering why the OP is using `Convert.ToInt16 vs Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: @MethodMan: it's a variable, it won't retain the value between postbacks as far as I recall and he uses it again in the Click event

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["ID"]);` this will have a value if it's not a Post back meaning on the initial Page_Load to persist the value I would recommend assigning the `Request.QueryString` value to `ViewState["aID"] =  Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"])`

Comment: A button click causes a postback does it not? Am I mistaken?

Comment: Surprisingly it worked. I completely missed that while using breaks. Excuse my noobishness in debugging I'm trying to learn. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: your answer is correct.. OP should not have this inside the if check `aID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["ID"]);`